# 2 way XML update between Booking.com and Google Calendar

Tags: google-schemas

Hi my name is David and I'm looking for a wizz answer on this one ;-)

A 2 way XML update between Booking.com and Google Calendar is it possible ?
And I don't mean the affiliate or something Booking.com I mean the Extranet.

So is channel management possible between Booking.com / Hotels.de and Google Calendar.

Thus being said that on http://googlesystem.blogspot.nl/2013/08/sites-that-integrate-with-google-now.html :
There's a long list of sites that integrate with Google Now: Air Berlin, Air Canada, Emirates, Booking.com, Lastminute.com, TicketWeb, Ticketfly, Orbitz, CheapTickets, OpenTable, Fandango, Rotten Tomatoes, Zillow and more.

This would be a great step for small business like mine..

Thanks in advance....
D.Corper

Answer (score -2):

Here I have built a calendar based on the booking data that cam out from MySQL database

http://www.jardim-dos-aloes.com/en/rooms.php?currencyid=3

It can be modified to read from an XML file.